# What is the main difference between SRAM and DRAM in the automotive industry?

Tags: memory, ram

What are the main differences between SRAM(static RAM) and DRAM(dynamic RAM) in the automotive industry?

What kind of memory does the different ECUs use?

I'm interested in the BCM(body control module), but all info regarding the ECUs will be useful for me.

I hope that this is the correct community to answer my questions, if not drop a line, will delete the question.

Comment: Simple google search would've done the trick

Comment: This reads like a homework question, and looks like you are asking the community to do the work for you. We help people, but we try to avoid damaging your opportunity to learn. There is no evidence of analysis or understanding, so it is likely to get closed. A web search will likely get good answers, or look at wikipedia. Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions, that are likely to get good answers. If you improve your question, by including your research, and explaining what you don't understand, it might not get closed.

Comment: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-sram-and-dram/

Comment: It's not a homework and I'm not asking the community to do the work for me. I think that this community is to answer a question the best possible way even though wikipedia can answer the question for me. Sorry if i'm wrong about the community. If this is not a correct question, vote to be closed, and i will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple SRAM cell is 6 transistors, and then you have something called "charge" amplifiers at the top and bottom of a column to "throw" the signal hard one way of the other.

A DRAM cell is two transistors, and a trench capacitor; however, you need to refresh it as it leaks down.   DRAM is more dense than SRAM.

There's actually a balance between speed/density and which one you would use.  External RAM is almost always DRAM, and internal cache has been traditionally SRAM; however, I use DRAM as cache when I have greater than 16MiB of cache because the total power is lower even with a refresh.   DRAM starts at a higher power, but the increase in power on a per-bit basis is slower than SRAM.  SRAM starts at a lower power but the total increase in power on a per-bit basis is higher.

This document will give you some answers on what this looks like for IBM (now GFs) processes:  http://www-07.ibm.com/tw/imc/seminar/download/2010/TW0AL02M-02.pdf

Answer (score 0):

SRAM is easier to interface (no need for a controller and/or refresh circuits) , more expensive per memory unit and eats more energy; often it is also faster